# Using Django, SimpleJWT checking User permission to show content belongs to his own company

Tags: django, authentication, permissions, access-token, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using React(front), Django(server-side), Simple JWT for User Auth Model and Postgres DB.

Let me explain my model: Company owns many properties, and each company has multiple users. As a user logs in, I want them to see a list of properties that belongs to their own company. As the user selects any property from the list, I need to again check if the user has permission and then run the queries. I am currently using Simple JWT for authentication. As the user logs in, the backend generates Access and Refresh tokens. With every request sent from the user side, I am sending JWT access token. On the server side, I want to decode the token, look at what company user belongs to, filter queries accordingly and send the JsonResponse.

Here is my Company Model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='company_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)   

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is the property model:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='prop_company', null = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    property_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    property_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.property_name
```

Here is the property data

```
class PropertyData(models.Model):
    
    data = models.ForeignKey(Property, related_name='property_data', null = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lat = model.FloatField(null=True)
    long = model.FloatField(null=True)
```

How should I handle the JWT token in the backend and check which company user belongs to, run queries accordingly and then send a success message along with the filtered data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `simple-JWT` you can customize your token claim. For this add this in your `serializer.py` file.

```py
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)

        # Add custom claims
        token['company_name'] = user.company_user.company_name # will add requested user company name in token
        # ...

        return token

# your views.py
class CustomTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

and also don't forget to update your **urls.py** file.

```py
from .views import CustomTokenObtainPairView


urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api/token/', CustomTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    ...
]
```

Hope this will solve your problem :)

Comment: Thanks Mubashar! That really helped me move in the right direction.

Comment: @Mubashar, you have send the companyname with the token, but then you still have to validate it right in the view? In the view  you need to check if the company belongs to the  user who makes the request?